# EF Core MySQL - multiple schemas in the same context

Tags: c#, mysql, database, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I am using EFCore to connect to a MySQL 5.7 server, and trying to connect my DbContext to multiple schemas at the same time, however it is always defaulting to the database that I have specified in my connection string

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "Database": "server=localhost; port=3306; user id=user; password=pass; database=schema1;"
  }
```

In my Context class I am trying to set up the entities to have different schemas using the `ToTable("table", "schema")` property

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>(entity =>
    {
        entity.ToTable("users", "schema1");
    });
    modelBuilder.Entity<Order>(entity =>
    {
        entity.ToTable("orders", "schema2");  
    }); 
}
```

Unfortunately when I try to retrieve data from the database I get the following error:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'Table 'schema1.orders' doesn't exist'
```

If I try something clearly wrong, like

```
entity.ToTable("schema2.orders", "schema2");
```

Then I unsurprisingly get the error:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'Table 'schema1.schema2.orders' doesn't exist'
```

So it appears as though it is always just using the `database` from the connection string.

If I modify the connection string to remove the `database`, which I believe is a step in the right direction.

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "Database": "server=localhost; port=3306; user id=user; password=pass;"
  }
```

Then I get the following error:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'No database selected'
```

Is what I am trying to achieve possible with a MySQL connection, or is support for this feature limited to specific DB engines

Comment: You may be running into https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=101236. It should be fixed in Connector/NET 8.0.24.

Comment: I just updated the question to specify that I am using MySQL 5.7, so I suspect that this is unrelated?

After a bit more research it appears to be that the issue might be that some DB engines have a distinction between Schema and Database, in that a database can have 1 or more schema, whereas in MySQL they are effectively the same thing. This leads me to believe that this EF Schema feature might not be supported for MySQL databases

Comment: What NuGet packages (and versions) are you using for MySQL + EFCore?

Comment: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore Version="5.0.2", MySql.EntityFrameworkCore Version="5.0.0-m8.0.23", MySQL Connector/NET 8.0.23. I followed the official MySQL documentation and it appears as though no other version has support for EFCore 5.0 https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework-core.html

Comment: So the bug report I linked to could well be related, because it's a bug in MySql.Data 8.0.22/8.0.23.

Comment: Ahh, for some reason I thought that I wasn't using MySql.Data. I thought that MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore used MySql.Data, but that MySql.EntityFrameworkCore didn't... Since I can't downgrade, I guess that I am stuck waiting for 8.0.24. Does that mean that `entity.ToTable("schema2.orders");` should have worked if it weren't for this bug?

Comment: This bug still exists for 8.0.26... still waiting for a fix.

Comment: Looks like it still exists in MySql.EntityFrameworkCore 7.0.2 as well, and that package seems to use MySql 8.0.33 under the hood